# How do I restrict untrusted code, now that CAS is deprecated?

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, code-access-security, trusted-vs-untrusted

Code access security (CAS) being now [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/5.0/code-access-security-apis-obsolete), what is the alternative, in .NET 6, when it comes to restricting the untrusted third-party code that is being executed by the application?

For instance, if the application makes it possible to add plugins to it, how it ensures that those plugins have very narrow permissions when it comes to accessing the file system, the network, the environment variables, etc.?